# Whole national market volume data

Tags: finance, europe, stock

I am looking for open data about daily whole stock exchange volumes in order to test the claim that [Amsterdam ousted London as Europe’s top share trading hub](https://www.ft.com/content/3dad4ef3-59e8-437e-8f63-f629a5b7d0aa) by the Financial Times. I didn't find the volume information [on yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFTSE?p=%5EFTSE&.tsrc=fin-srch) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another secondary source of the info:

Bloomberg: https://archive.is/omvKx

[image: market trading geo share]

It turns out the calculation was made by "Cboe Global Markets", who will have real-time market data access ($$$).

---

I tried to recreate the numbers but for the London exchange I only found

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/reports?tab=market-summary

([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210212092926if_/https://www.londonstockexchange.com/reports?tab=market-summary))

[image]

where the daily trading amount is on average ~£4 billion (see [excel download](https://docs.londonstockexchange.com/sites/default/files/reports/Order%20book%20trading_104.xlsx) for more days).

I couldn't find any recent data for the Amsterdam exchange.

---

So without reading the actual report from Cboe, it's hard to know where they are getting their numbers.